# Merge 3 multiindex dataframes to make one multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have 3 dataframes:

df1 is

```
                   Total  Total  Total
Tool Technology     One    Two   Three
Alt    AI            15     6     9
```

df2 is

```
                   Check  Check  Check
Tool Technology     One    Two   Three
Alt    AI           10      4     6
```

df3 is

```
                   Uncheck  Uncheck  Uncheck
Tool Technology     One      Two      Three
Alt    AI           18        11        7
```

After merging the final data frame should be like

```
                   Total  Total  Total   Check  Check  Check   Uncheck   Uncheck  Uncheck
Tool Technology     One    Two   Three    One    Two   Three    One       Two      Three
Alt    AI           10      4     6        15     6     9       18         11        7
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried concating  (`pd.concat`) the dataframes on axis=1?

Comment: Yes i tried but in that Tool and Technology repeat every time

Comment: if `Tool` and `Technology` repeats, may be it is not an index but rather a column. Try `dfs = [df1,df2,df3]` , then `pd.concat((df.set_index(['Tool','Technology']) for df in dfs),axis=1)` ?

Comment: This is multiindex so this is giving error like: KeyError: "None of ['Tool', 'Technology'] are in the columns". 
I check df1.columns: 
MultiIndex([('Unnamed: 0_level_0',    'Tool'),
            ('Unnamed: 1_level_0',  'Technology'),......])

Comment: Seems your example doesnt fit the data itself...

Answer (score 0):

Three approaches to merge work with multi-index rows.  It's not clear if your DataFrames have multi-index columns as well.  Provide using `to_dict()` method

```
import io
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                   Total  Total  Total
Tool Technology     One    Two   Three
Alt    AI            15     6     9  """), sep="\s+", header=1).set_index(["Tool","Technology"])
df1 = df1.rename(columns={c:f"Total {c}" for c in df1.columns})
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                   Check  Check  Check
Tool Technology     One    Two   Three
Alt    AI           10      4     6"""), sep="\s+", header=1).set_index(["Tool","Technology"])
df2 = df2.rename(columns={c:f"Check {c}" for c in df2.columns})

print(pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).to_string())
print(df1.join(df2).to_string())
print(df1.merge(df2, on=["Tool","Technology"]).to_string())
```

### output

```
                 Total One  Total Two  Total Three  Check One  Check Two  Check Three
Tool Technology                                                                      
Alt  AI                 15          6            9         10          4            6
                 Total One  Total Two  Total Three  Check One  Check Two  Check Three
Tool Technology                                                                      
Alt  AI                 15          6            9         10          4            6
                 Total One  Total Two  Total Three  Check One  Check Two  Check Three
Tool Technology                                                                      
Alt  AI                 15          6            9         10          4            6
```